# Stored procedure: how can I set a field value in the returned data without changing the tables it came from?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

```
SELECT 
        EQ.EventQuestId, 
        EQ.QuestionText, 
        EQ.HelpText, 
        EQ.EventQuestOptType, 
        EQ.DisplayOrder AS QuestDisplayOrder, 
        EQO.EventQuestOptId, 
        EQO.OptionText, 
        EQO.IsOtherSpecify,
        STJC.STJCategory,
        EQO.DisplayOrder AS OptDisplayOrder,
        EA.EventId, EA.AnswerText 
            FROM EventQuest EQ 
            INNER JOIN EventQuestOpt EQO 
                ON EQ.EventQuestId = EQO.EventQuestId 
            LEFT JOIN EventAnswer EA 
                ON EA.EventQuestId = EQ.EventQuestId 
                    AND EA.EventQuestOptId = EQO.EventQuestOptId
                    AND EventId = @EventId
            LEFT JOIN dbo.STJCategories STJC 
                ON STJC.STJID = EQO.STJID
                    WHERE EQO.Status <> 'false'
                        ORDER BY EQ.DisplayOrder, EQO.DisplayOrder
```

I have this in my stored proc. I want to set the EQ.QuestionText to the STJC.STJCategory value wherever EQ.QuestionText = "example". I just want this in the returned result, not in table it came from. How do I go about this as I've never tried to do this before and have no clue where to begin with that, if it's possible.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: What do you want to show in that column if QuestionText = 'example' and STJCategory is NULL (either because the underlying value is NULL or because the left join did not produce a matching row)? A few rows of sample data and the desired results from the query in some kind of tabular format are usually a ***LOT*** more useful than a word problem.

Comment: Thanks all! That's pretty clever. One more step in the opposite direction of newbieness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `case` for that:

```
select  case 
        when EQ.QuestionText = 'example' then STJC.STJCategory 
        else EQ.QuestionText 
        end as QuestionText
```

Answer (score 2):

use a CASE statement

```
SELECT 
        EQ.EventQuestId, 
        CASE EQ.QuestionText WHEN 'example' 
        THEN STJC.STJCategory ELSE EQ.QuestionText END QuestionText , 
        EQ.HelpText, 
        EQ.EventQuestOptType, 
        EQ.DisplayOrder AS QuestDisplayOrder, 
        EQO.EventQuestOptId, 
        EQO.OptionText, 
        EQO.IsOtherSpecify,
        STJC.STJCategory,
        EQO.DisplayOrder AS OptDisplayOrder,
        EA.EventId, EA.AnswerText 
            FROM EventQuest EQ 
            INNER JOIN EventQuestOpt EQO 
                ON EQ.EventQuestId = EQO.EventQuestId 
            LEFT JOIN EventAnswer EA 
                ON EA.EventQuestId = EQ.EventQuestId 
                    AND EA.EventQuestOptId = EQO.EventQuestOptId
                    AND EventId = @EventId
            LEFT JOIN dbo.STJCategories STJC 
                ON STJC.STJID = EQO.STJID
                    WHERE EQO.Status <> 'false'
                        ORDER BY EQ.DisplayOrder, EQO.DisplayOrder
```

Comment: Wow, don't everybody jump on this all at once now. :-)

Comment: It's OK, I've deleted mine and +1d you both for beating me by seconds. :-)

Comment: I upped your comment as a consolation prize, @AaronBertrand. =)